# how correctly use toDate in group query

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on a query which is grouping records per day and counting them  on MongoDB 
here is my query

```
db.getCollection('CustomerApplications').aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: { day: { $dayOfYear: { $toDate: "$data.submittedAt" }}, year: { $year: { $toDate: "$data.submittedAt" } } },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

$data.submittedAt is a double so I need to convert it to date then pull $dayOfYear from it 
but I get

> Unrecognized expression '$toDate'

my data structure is like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c942f50dae240feb1942b00"),
    "data" : {
        "id" : "624c0d17-b683-4c89-9d7c-011577d4e3b8",
        "email" : "i8888@eee.com",
        "name" : "ianh",
        "phoneNumber" : "+1222222",
        "score" : 12,
        "status" : "PENDING",
        "submittedAt" : 1553215312006.0,
        "surveyVersion" : "1"
    },
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-03-21T00:41:52.192Z")
}
```

any Idea is this doable in MongoDB if yes how to correctly do it?

Comment: I created sample data
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5c9431a35af55c2d7e38fa71"),
 "submittedAt" : 1553215849377,
 "name" : "Alec"
},

{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5c9431a35af55c2d7e38fa70"),
 "submittedAt" : 1553215849377,
 "name" : "Gerald"
} then I execute your query. its working fine. can you provide content of CustomerApplications?

Comment: $toDate is working for you ?

Comment: yeah its working. here is the result {
 "_id" : {
  "day" : 81,
  "year" : 2019
 },
 "count" : 2
}

Comment: I tried your sample data. its working fine. I can't find why you are getting error. where did you run your query?

Comment: I'm testing at Robo 3T , and my MongoDB version is v4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

```
$toDate New in version 4.0. Please check your version
```

Can you try with this.

```
db.getCollection('CustomerApplications').aggregate(
[
 {
   $group:
     {
      _id : { $substr: ["$data.submittedAt", 0, 10] },
       count: { $sum: 1 }
     }
 }
])
```

May this will help you

```
$toDate - Converts a value to a date (New in version 4.0)

$dayOfMonth - Returns the day of the month for a date as a number between 1 and 31

$dayOfYear - Returns the day of the year for a date as a number between 1 and 366
```

Comment: my version is v4.0.4